# Inferred type is incorrect when using extended class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider the following code:

```js
class Annotation {
  static defaultValues = {
    id: null
  }
}

class AnotherAnn extends Annotation {
  static defaultValues = {
    ...Annotation.defaultValues,
    id2: null
  }
}

class YetAnotherAnnotation extends Annotation {}

const x = [AnotherAnn, YetAnotherAnnotation]
```

In the code above, the inferred type of x is `(typeof YetAnotherAnnotation)[]` instead of `(typeof YetAnotherAnnotation | typeof AnotherAnn)[]`. Can someone explain why ?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=45&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB28D2AXMKCWT7QN4FgAoaaCNTYaAEwFMAzMAVxBQDUwRGaYBePIkiQxUAXNHjMQA6AF8icwkVCQYCVAAsaAJwQ4aADxQ14VVYlTosOAsVLkMlWg2ZsOXXv1skAdL90XMbG8nJhZ2Tm4AGmkhKgAmMQkQKVsFBSVwKGgATRoUNRRNHXN7bGgDIxMzZFLrdMJgbDJofWg+AG0Cot1InLyu7X9agF0gA)

Comment: I believe this is because TS has structural type system and compiler does not see any difference between `AnotherAnn` and `YetAnotherAnnotation`. Try to add any property to `YetAnotherAnnotation` and you will see that `x` will be infered as you expect. Unfortunately, TS does not treat `classes` as nominal types. Btw, same behaviour with empty enums